# concatenated dataframe sum of a column, or difference between two columns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, concatenation

i have created one concatenated dataframe obtained from 2 different dataframe.
the layout is ok of the concat df but when i try to make the sum of one column i obtain one errore.
below the code using for the sum column

```
TotalVolumeAsk = concatenated_df['VolumeAsk'].sum()
print ("Column Volume Ask sum:",Total)
```

the output is

```
Column Volume Ask sum: 0.010000000.023380000.009390000.061090000.004690000.010000000.011250000.070510000.004000000.041750000.007460000.000530000.004000000.001060000.008000000.052200000.010000000.004000000.001000000.020000000.069790002.390000000.00401000
```

i think one only value for the column...how can i solve this problem?

also if i use the code below to calculate the difference between two columns i have this error.

code use for the difference between 2 column:

```
concatenated_df['spread']=concatenated_df['b']-concatenated_df['c']
```

error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

thank you for the help.

Comment: provide minimal data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be help if you add expected output. And how are you getting such value for `sum`?

Comment: my expected output is one only number derived from the sum of each row in the column.

Comment: convert columns to float: concatenated_df[['VolumeAsk', 'b', 'c']].astype(float)

Comment: nothing change...i have tri with the float and also using astype string

Comment: try again added 'VolumeAsk'.  The last error says that your data is in the form of a string.

Comment: Print the types of all columns: print (concatenated_df.dtypes)

Comment: nothing...this it the output of types print (concatenated_df.dtypes)

PriceAsk          object
VolumeAsk         object
Pricebid          object
Volumebid         object
TotalVolumeAsk    object
dtype: object
 but i still have the output for the sum always for each string and not for the total....others advice?

Comment: If the return types are object, it's most likely a string. And you need numbers, namely the float type. It's better to show a few lines of your dataframe, so it will be easier to help (five is enough).

Comment: this is the first 5 string of my df. (already setting with float )
" VolumeAsk  Volumebid  PriceAsk  Pricebid
0  0.04359  0.08858  21270.07  21269.12
1  0.00400  0.04000  21270.08  21269.10
2  0.00133  0.00268  21270.43  21269.02
3  0.01410  0.00541  21270.44  21268.74
4  0.00575  0.09000  21270.60  21268.73"

Comment: I gave an example below, substitute your values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own dataframe, if you remove the line where the columns are converted to float, then the same errors will occur.
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bid':['1.2', '1.4', '1.5'], 'ask':['1.5', '1.7', '2.1']})
df[['bid', 'ask']] = df[['bid', 'ask']].astype(float)#If you remove this line, then the same errors will occur
df['spred'] = df['ask'] - df['bid']

TotalAsk = df['ask'].sum()

print ("Column Ask sum:", TotalAsk)
print(df)
```

Output

```
Column Ask sum: 5.300000000000001

   bid  ask  spred
0  1.2  1.5   -0.3
1  1.4  1.7   -0.3
2  1.5  2.1   -0.6
```

If you print the column types before the conversion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bid':['1.2', '1.4', '1.5'], 'ask':['1.5', '1.7', '2.1']})
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output

```
bid    object
ask    object
```

after:

```
df[['bid', 'ask']] = df[['bid', 'ask']].astype(float)#If you remove this line, then the same errors will occur
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output

```
bid    float64
ask    float64
```

That's why I was asking about the data type of your columns. And you have it object, that is, not numeric. The values in them are not numbers.

Comment: I do not resolve..because i do not need an other datafame with only bid and ask volume... do i must create a new df of only volume for bid and ask? i have already the complete dataframe...

Comment: No, if I understand you correctly. Just convert the column to numbers. Volume will probably be of type int. Just understand that the data that you received from a file or from somewhere else is not numeric and needs to be converted in order to do calculations with it.

Comment: Convert the volume like this: concatenated_df['VolumeAsk'] =  concatenated_df['VolumeAsk'].astype(int)          Usually string data is obtained when reading data from a file, they are all string there, even for example 3.27 will be string. Column conversion is not creating a new foreme, if that's what you mean?

Comment: i have resolved using   "concatenated_df=pd.concat([depth_df_ask,depth_df_bid],axis=True).astype(float)"

Comment: just now I saw the volume you have, too, of type float. This is possible in cryptocurrencies. Usually the volume is in whole numbers of stocks, futures.